# Javascript How to search in array by field

Tags: javascript

I have a variable which holds this data:

```
{"main":[
  {"id":"123","name":"name 1"},
  {"id":"234","name":"name 2"}

  ]
}
```

I know the id of the data I want to search.

My question is...How do I search for the name of id 234 (for example) is thw data above?

Comment: Use JSON.parse().

Comment: iterate in it with for and compare each record.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> *The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.*

```js
var object = {
  "main": [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "name 1"
  }, {
    "id": "234",
    "name": "name 2"
  }]
};
var toFind = "234";
var filtered = object.main.filter(function(el) {
  return el.id === toFind;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

If there is only one object in the `array`, `for-loop` with `break` could be preferred.

```js
var object = {
  "main": [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "name 1"
  }, {
    "id": "234",
    "name": "name 2"
  }]
};
var toFind = "234";
for (var i = 0, len = object.main.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (object.main[i].id === toFind) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log(object.main[i].name);
```

Comment: why use filter? it will iterate over all array

Comment: @pwolaq – OP may have more than one object having similar ID...

Comment: OP said that he wants to get a name, not array of objects with names

Comment: @pwolaq – Not sure who is correct, I have added another approach as well... I hope it covers your point as well...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find()` if id's are unique.

```js
var data = {"main":[
  {"id":"123","name":"name 1"},
  {"id":"234","name":"name 2"}
  ]
}

var name = data.main.find(function(o) {
  return o.id == '234';
}).name;

console.log(name)
```

Comment: `find` is part of ES6

Comment: not to mention it will cause an error if there is no element with given id

Answer (score 2):

In ES5 environment, you could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), if you expect only one result.

```js
var data = { "main": [{ "id": "123", "name": "name 1" }, { "id": "234", "name": "name 2" }] },
    result;

data.main.some(function (a) {
    if (a.id === '234') {
        result = a;
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

When you expect more than one result set, you may better use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var data = { "main": [{ "id": "123", "name": "name 1" }, { "id": "234", "name": "name 2a" }, { "id": "234", "name": "name 2" }] },
    result = data.main.filter(function (a) {
        return a.id === '234';
    });

console.log(result);
```

In ES6 environment, you could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for the first found element, but if there are more to find, then use `Array#filter`.

```js
var data = { "main": [{ "id": "123", "name": "name 1" }, { "id": "234", "name": "name 2" }] },
    result = data.main.find(a => a.id === '234');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find all matching elements and return them as a new array.

To find just the first match, you can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (ES2015+).